# PrimeFaces tag code completion does not work in Netbeans

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces

I have tried to create new web app in netbeans , and then i add jsf framework library when i press (CTRL+SPACE) completion work properly for jsf tags ,but when i added primefaces with it when i press(CTRL+SPACE) jsf and primefaces tags in completion didn't appear but work properly .

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: how to make completion work for jsf and primefaces tags work ?

Comment: have you checked the netbeans fora?

Comment: seriously? http://forums.netbeans.org/

Comment: thanks i will checked it

Comment: Completion in NetBeans works for me. Did you add the namespace to your page (`xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`)?